# Trying to the pagination in Laravel but "Collection::links does not exist."

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-pagination

Hi so I'm trying to the a pagination on my table to display only for example 3 users and have various links for other pages to display more users but it's getting me a error that "Collection::links does not exist."

This is my controller:

```
$users = User::paginate(3);
return view('perfil', compact('users'));
```

And this is my link on the view:

```
{!! $users->links() !!}
```

What I'm doin wrong? Thank you in advance.

Comment: what version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: I'm using Laravel 8.

Answer (score 0):

you have 3 rows and because of this no pagination will show,
in order to show it your row number must be > pageination

Comment: Didn't understand sorry